# WordPress oEmbed W3C Validation

Tags: validation, oembed

I recently built a theme that utilises the [oEmbed](http://oembed.com) feature in WordPress.

Where possible, I like my themes to validate via W3C. The content of the website is driven by Vimeo videos, so I'm getting well over 30 validation errors.

The validation tool flags the following attributes:

```
frameborder
webkitallowfullscreen
mozallowfullscreen
```

I'm aware that the `allowfullscreen` attribute is required for HTML5 players, but wondered if there's a solution that will pass validation?

I can see that `webkitallowfullscreen` and `mozallowfullscreen` are no longer required: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`class-oembed.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-oembed.php) file reveals some of the available filters regarding the oEmbeds.

We can use the [`oembed_result`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L295) or [`oembed_dataparse`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L549) filters to modify the HTML fetched from Vimeo before it's cached in the post meta. Here's an example for the latter:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', function( $return, $data, $url )
{
    // Target only Vimeo:
    if(
            is_object( $data ) 
        &&  property_exists( $data, 'provider_name' )
        &&  'Vimeo' === $data->provider_name
    )
    {
        // Remove the unwanted attributes:
        $return = str_ireplace(
            array( 
                'frameborder="0"', 
                'webkitallowfullscreen', 
                'mozallowfullscreen' 
            ),
            '',
            $return
        );
    }
    return $return;
}, 10, 3 );
```

### Example:

**Before:**

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/32001208" 
        width="584" 
        height="329" 
        frameborder="0" 
        title="Earth" 
        webkitallowfullscreen 
        mozallowfullscreen 
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**After:**

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/32001208" 
        width="584" 
        height="329"  
        title="Earth"   
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

### Additional notes on `xhtml`:

If you check out the [Vimeo oEmbed API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed), there's a `xhtml` parameter with the default `xhtml=false`. You can try for example:

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/32001208
```

vs.

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/32001208&xhtml=true
```

So instead of:

```
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
```

we get:

```
 webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" 
 mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" 
 allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
```

If we want to aim for *XHTML* validation, we could try to modify this via the `oembed_remote_get_args`, for example. But I didn't test that.

Comment: Works perfectly. A superb answer which I'm sure many people will benefit from. Thank you!

Comment: I used this solution, but it didn't work → https://www.screencast.com/t/Ql7njNlFIS5l  Also this one → `Error: Attribute gesture not allowed on element iframe at this point.`  `Error: Attribute allows not allowed on element iframe at this point.`

Comment: @TheWPNovice The example I posted assumes Vimeo, but you're using Youtube. The oEmbed providers might be using different iframe attributes. so the example might need some adjustments.

Comment: @birgire, I am a novice sir. Thanks for replying. can you Please suggest the solution/recommendation. Help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: We could try to adjust the `'Vimeo' === $data->provider_name` part, I'm not able to test now but I would guess `'Youtube' === $data->provider_name` ? If that works, then the next step would be to adjust the array in the `str_ireplace()` to match the problematic iframe attributes..

Comment: @birgire I tried this [code](https://www.screencast.com/t/mJRxUZ5t6). [Error 1](https://www.screencast.com/t/TCZXEDEw7), [Error 2](https://www.screencast.com/t/sFjQqJX3uBm), [Error 3](https://www.screencast.com/t/nIZphYBUJ)